# Travel inside the EU with expired student visa

Tags: france, visa-expiration, portugal, brazilian-citizens, student-visas

I am a Brazilian who is currently a student in Lisbon, I would like to travel to France in a few weeks and my student visa is expired, however, I am still enrolled in the university for next semester, so I only have a document from the university but I do not have an appointment with the immigration to get a visa extension yet. Do I have the risk of being deported if I travel to France right now under these circumstances?

Comment: Yes, but probably to Portugal and not to Brazil. Due to the present restrictions, the likelihood of being caught is very high and not advised.